# binary search tree null pointer exception

Tags: java, pointers, tree, null, binary-search-tree

I guess I am way of with my code, so you dont need to look to much into that, just check the first lines of code.I cant understand what is wrong with where the error happens.

```
public boolean add(E x) {
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(root);
    if(root.equals(null)){
        root.equals(x);
        return true;
    }
    if(root.equals(x)){        
        return false;
    }
    BinaryNode<E> save = root;   //create new nod copy of root

    while((!save.left.equals(x)) && (!save.left.equals(null))){ //check so save.nex isnt x and that save.next exists
    save=save.left;
    }
    if(save.left.equals(null)){
        save = root;  //puts save back to root again
        while((!save.right.equals(x)) && (!save.right.equals(null))){
            save=save.right;
        }

        if(save.right.equals(null)){
            save.right.equals(x);
            return true;
        }


} return false;
    }
```

I get the error at the line `if(root.equals(null)){` It's just an if statement, I am not trying to acess something that doesnt exist??

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `root.equals(null)`? Have you tried just using `if(root == null)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `root` *does* equal `null` then you *are* trying to access something that doesn't exist by calling the `equals` method on it.  Just use `if(root == null)`.